# iPhone save the rotated UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to save the rotated image to the photo library.
I have a UIImageView in which the image is displayed. I used the below snippet to flip the image. The rotated image does get displayed since I transform the image view. But while saving the image I get the original image (not flipped). How do I save a flipped image?

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(__ANGLE__) ((__ANGLE__) / 180.0 * M_PI)
    CGAffineTransform cgCTM = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(180));
    imageView.transform = cgCTM;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the

```
UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext
```

method.